# Download text content from variable

Tags: php, string, variables, text, download

i created a php script which creates a text string, which I display on the screen.
Do you know how it's possible to download only the variable content as a text file? I alrady tried something like this:

```
...
<body>
<?php
$download_me = "download me...";
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");
echo $download_me;
?>
</body>
...
```

but this creates a text file with the whole html document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
download me...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you 've posted shouldn't do that. You must have some other code that's echoing the HTML.

Comment: You can't mix a download and HTML in the same output.

Comment: The errant `*/` at the end of the pasted code implies that all of this code is actually *commented out* in the source.  Which would explain why it's not doing what you would expect it to do...

Comment: @David: sry the *\ was just a copy paste failure.

Comment: @make: The updated code is one big syntax error.  It's neither valid HTML nor valid PHP.  It sounds like the problem here isn't that the code doesn't work, but that you're missing some fundamental introductory concepts for writing PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code *by itself* will do what you want it to do:

```
<?php
$download_me = "download me...";
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");
echo $download_me;
?>
```

However, you're wrapping that code in HTML code.  Which means two things:

1. You are attempting to modify headers after you've already begun sending output.
2. The text being echoed isn't the only content, you're also outputting the HTML around it.

The first issue is probably producing errors in your server logs.  If the code is quietly ignoring that and continuing to execute, the second issue would explain the output you're seeing.  You see HTML because, well, you're outputting HTML.

If you don't want to output HTML, remove the HTML from your output.  Just use the code which sends the text file response.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I will check the server log as soon a s possible. To your last paragraph: but how? I create the whole content with user input in the same file. I can't just remove it.

Comment: @make: If this code is part of a larger code file, you would conditionally execute this code or other code based on however you currently determine when you want to download the file vs. output the HTML.  However, it's generally better to separate these things into different server-side resources, since they produce very different responses.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a file with those contents:

```
<?php
    $download_me = "download me...";
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");
    echo $download_me;
?>
```

And it worked, it downloaded as a txt file.

Comment: Yes generally it works but if you put content before it's also in the downloaded text file

Comment: You can't have any content before.

Comment: This will turn the entire webpage into a text file.